# Is "at least" a parenthetical expression requiring commas?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is this sentence punctuated correctly with no commas surrounding "at least," or does it need them?

Why or why not?
Adverbial phrase? Essential or nonessential? 
I have been looking at it too long and can't tell anymore!

> Well, there was the one time at least the mother had him in the store.

**N.B. This is a transcript of actual testimony in a court case being transcribed, so the wording cannot be changed.**

Comment: Delete _at least_. It does no work in the sentence. Rewrite the sentence as: _Well, the mother had him in the store at least once_ or _Well, there was the one time that the mother had him in the store_. "At least" is merely a verbosity in the original sentence. It's strictly colloquial spoken English and shouldn't be written unless you want dialog to show how thoughtless the speaker is, just tossing words in as interjections because the speaker can't integrate tongue and brain.

Comment: @BillFranke, without “at least” the sentence would say it happened once, a single time.  The current form allows for multiple instances, and “at least” is neither redundant nor verbose.

Comment: @jwpat7: True. But _at least_ is placed wrong. It normally precedes the quantifier it modifies (_at least once_), so this tends to get read as _at least the mother had him in the store_ instead of _the one time at least_. Bill has better suggestions for rewriting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should parenthesize the expression with commas in that sentence:

> Well, there was the one time, at least, the mother had him in the store.

If you don't do so, the sentence becomes ambiguous. Do you mean to emphasize "the one time at least" or "at least the mother"? It's not clear. But setting off the expression with commas eliminates confusion.

Note that you could accomplish the same thing by not using ellipsis. The word *that* is implied but omitted in your example. Put it back and the ambiguity goes away:

> Well, there was the one time at least that the mother had him in the store.

I would still prefer commas there, however:

> Well, there was the one time, at least, that the mother had him in the store.

Comment: That's it- ambiguity! Thank you so much for clearing that up. I'm editing a court transcript, so I cannot change the text, only the punctuation.

Comment: Thank you all- the lawyer had asked the witness: On how many occasions have you been in the company of her son? The answer was: Never. And the next statement was made by the lawyer: Well, there was the one time at least when the mother had him in the store.

Comment: @jennifer: The normal way to give thanks on SE sites is to upvote and/or accept answers.

Comment: @jennifer (2 up): That worries me. The omission of the famous 'cannibals' comma' is enough to change an announcement that tea is ready to a possible death-threat: "We're going to eat, John." Such scope for error! And nuances of tone must be missed in a transcript. And polysemy will almost certainly be more liable to cause confusion in the written word. I think recordings should replace transcriptions.

Answer (score 0):

- Well, there was the one time, at least, the mother had him in the store.
- Well, there was the one time at least, the mother had him in the store.
- Well, there was the one time, at least the mother had him in the store.

All three have different meanings or, at least for the first two, implications.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is seven years to late to help the OP, but ...

From the context, I conclude that the lawyer wanted to rebut the testimony that the witness had never met the young man. The OP would know, but it seems the lawyer is stating that the witness was in the young man's presence at least once. On that occasion, he was in the store with his mother.

The discussion focused on comma placement and failed to consider other orthography that could alleviate the ambiguity.

Thus, I suggest as a possibility:

Well, there was the one time, at least; when the mother had him in the store.

Yes, the oft-neglected, nearly forgotten semicolon can stand us in good stead here. Placing the semicolon before 'at least' changes the meaning but still alleviates the ambiguity.